# Numpy 3D array multiply 2D array

Tags: python, numpy

I got a 3D array with `W = shape(D,C,F)` and a 2D array with `X = shape(D,F)`. And I want to output a matrix with shape `(D,C)`.

Currently, what I do is to iterate the rows in `X` and `W`

```
for row in X.shape[0]:
    X[row].dot(W[row].T)
```

Is there any way that I do not need to do the iteration? Can I do it just like `X.dot(W.T)`? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try indexing `W.T` in the statement you have. It is difficult for me to see without a little more detail, but something like `X.dot(W.T[:1])` seems like it might work in your case.